# How to change (DOM) CSS with current HTML height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to make a function that changes the CSS to the current height when I click a button. It won’t read the current height.

```js
var height = $(window).height();

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("bodypacity").style.height = height;
}
```

```css
#bodypacity {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menunav"> <span id="menu" style="" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="logo.png"></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's wrong with provided code? Anything works unexpected?

Comment: Where and how is `openNav` called? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: HTML

<ul class="menunav">
<span id="menu" style="" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
<a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="logo.png"></a>
</ul>

CSS
#bodypacity{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I want to get the current page height so it would be more flexible than if I put exact size like document.getElementById("bodypacity").style.height = "1000px";

Comment: @SteveRuru Please [edit] your question. Where is the `bodypacity` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the `height` of the `window` and set the element to equal `height`. You're very close to achieve that, all you need is to add `"px"` to the final `height`, because `$(window).height()` returns only number, so you can set the actual height using `$(window).height() + "px"`, and it will be `document.getElementById("target").style.height = height + "px";` in your case:

```js
var height = $(window).height();
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("target").style.height = height + "px";
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#target {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  <button onclick="openNav()">Set Height</button>
</div>
```